# How to suppress field from GraphQLClientRequest request body?

Tags: kotlin, graphql-kotlin

When I use ExpediaGroup graphql-kotlin client to call a GQL query, it inserts a field besides the `query`, `variables` and `operationName`. I understand this field comes from my extended class constructor parameter. I don't need this field. Is there a way to suppress it?

My class:

```
class SubmissionQuery(val submissionUuid: String): GraphQLClientRequest<SubmissionQuery.Result> { ... }
```

Request body:

```
{
   "submissionUuid":"0c00a000-3f03-4f57-b999-7082e2a53fa1",
   "operationName":"",
   "query":"query($uuid: String!) {myQuery(uuid: $uuid){uuid}}",
   "variables":{"uuid":"0c00a000-3f03-4f57-b999-7082e2a53fa1"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it in the last minute: just change the parameter to private in constructor.

```
class SubmissionQuery(private val submissionUuid: String)
```